# Log in Salesforce using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, authentication, salesforce

I'm building a login page from where I would like to connect to my salesforce.com account.
The idea is that if the username/password is wrong, I leave the user on my website and otherwise I redirect him to the salesforce panel.

To check if the username password exists, I use the Salesforce PHP Toolkit. And when I see that the user has entered a legit account, I use cURL to post the username and password to the form that is supposedly handling the login.

Here's some bits of the code:

```
$url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
$fields = array(
      'username' => urlencode($username),
      'pw' => urlencode($pw),
      'un' => urlencode($username),
      'width' => urlencode($width),
      'height' => urlencode($height),
      'hasRememberUn' => urlencode(true),
      'startURL' => urlencode(''),
      'loginURL' => urlencode(''),
      'loginType' => urlencode(''),
      'useSecure' => urlencode(true),
      'local' => urlencode(''),
      'lt' => urlencode('standard'),
      'qs' => urlencode(''),
      'locale' => urlencode('uk'),
      'oauth_token' => urlencode(''),
      'login' => urlencode(''),
      'serverid' => urlencode(''),
      'display' => urlencode('page')
  );

  $fields_string =''; 
  foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
  rtrim($fields_string,'&');
  $ch = curl_init();

  /* Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

I inspected the source of the login page of salesforce.com to see what post values it needs which I put it in the code above.

The problem is that whenever I input a valid account, it redirects me to the login page (so I am not logged in) of salesforce.com saying

> You have attempted to access a page that requires a salesforce.com login. If you are already a user of the system, please login below.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

urlencode() is not the proper method to encode your data with, since you're not passing the data in a URL.

CURL can take an array and automatically convert the data in it to a POST-able data set. You don't have to do the encoding yourself. Simply do

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip ! But that doesn't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_POST` takes a bool, not the number of fields you're posting.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Additionally, if the service uses cookies for session storage, you'll need to add a cookie jar. From http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/cookiejar.html

For the initial authentication request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```

And for subsequent requests using it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
```